# Query showing extra row

Tags: java, sql

```
<%
                String qTotal = "SELECT MsThread.ID, MsThread.ThreadName, Count(MsThread.ThreadName) AS TotalPost, ThreadCategory FROM MsThread LEFT OUTER JOIN MsPosts ON MsThread.ThreadName = MsPosts.ThreadName GROUP BY MsThread.ID, MsThread.ThreadName, MsThread.ThreadCategory;";

                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qTotal);

                    int size = 0;

                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                        out.print(size++);%><br/><%
                    }
                    rs.first();   
                        out.println(rs.getString("id"));    
                    rs.next();
                        out.println(rs.getString("id"));    
                    rs.next();
                        out.println(rs.getString("id"));    
                    if(!rs.next())
                    {   
                        out.println("no data");
                    }
                    else
                        out.println(rs.getString("id"));  
              %>
```

Guys, here's what happened, when i tried to run the query it shows 3 result (http://s29.postimg.org/6qiv9kc9j/ss_forum.png) but when i run the 
    while(rs.next())size++;
it returns 4, and when i try to show the data, it gives me invalid cursor state, so is there anything wrong with my query?

thanks

Comment: Is this JDBC? How did you initialize stmt ?. By default when you call the createStatement() in a connection it will be a rs of "TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY". The first() method should throw an exception if this is the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default sensitivity of a ResultSet is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, which means that it cannot be scrolled; you cannot call any of these methods that move the cursor -

- previous
- first
- last
- beforeFirst
- afterLast
- relative(int rows)
- absolute(int row)

Except `next`, your ResultSet cannot be scrolled. If your resultset if created with default sensitivity then they can not be scrolled using  `rs.first();` after moving to last end via `rs.next()` in while statement.

```
but when i run the while(rs.next())size++; it returns 4,
```

When a ResultSet object is first created, the cursor is positioned before the first row, so you are getting 4.

Thanks